# One on one reflexive relationship ef core

Tags: c#, database-design, entity-framework-core

How to model a one on one reflexive relationship ef core.

I Have this Model that can either be a parent or a child of a model of the same type. Think of it as a spouses relationship.

A one on one on the same table.

I was thinking option 1:

```
int? parentId;
int? childId;

modelBuilder.Entity<ENTITY>()
                .HasOne(o => o.Parent)
                .WithOne(a => a.Child)
                .HasForeignKey<Document>(o => o.parentId)

modelBuilder.Entity<ENTITY>()
                .HasOne(o => o.Child)
                .WithOne(a => a.Parent)
                .HasForeignKey<ENTITY>(o => o.childId)
```

Or option 2:

```
int? relationId
bool parent
modelBuilder.Entity<ENTITY>()
               .HasOne(o => o.Relation)
               .WithOne(a => a.Relation)
               .HasForeignKey<ENTITY>(o => o.relationId)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2º option is the correct one i think.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ENTITY>()
        .HasOne<Relation>(e => e.Relation)
        .WithOne(r => r.Entity)
        .HasForeignKey<ENTITY>(r => r.relationId);
```

This link can be useful.
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-one-to-one-relationship-using-fluent-api-in-ef-core.aspx
Hope it helps!